# How to configure doom emacs to work with React.js + Typescript?

Tags: doom

I'm starting to use Doom Emacs and want to know how to work with a frontend project that uses React.js with Typescript.

Comment: Specific questions for this site, please. If you want to solicit general advice, or you want opinions on the "best" way to do something, consider using a discussion site, such as Reddit. Thx.

Comment: My question is how to configure doom to use React.js + typescript.
I don't know which packages I should use, this is not a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

Doom has TS support in its [JS module](https://docs.doomemacs.org/latest/#/modules/lang/javascript), and if by mentioning React you meant TSX then it has a mode for that too: `typescript-tsx-mode`. You can find it by hitting `SPC h f` and searching for "tsx"